# Add webMap as layer with ArcGIS mapView for iOS app project

Tags: ios, objective-c, arcgis

I'm trying to code in a basic ArcGIS workflow into my iOS project. I am new to this platform and can use some pointers. My workflow is as follows.

1.) Create mapView displaying satellite (world style) map.
2.) Add a public webMap from my user account on ArcGIS Online as an overlay/layer on the satellite map.

What I've tried

```
//.h

#import <ArcGIS/ArcGIS.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AGSWebMapDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet AGSMapView *mapView;

//.m

// Add basemap

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer"];
AGSTiledMapServiceLayer *tiledLayer = [AGSTiledMapServiceLayer tiledMapServiceLayerWithURL:url];
[self.mapView addMapLayer:tiledLayer withName:@"Basemap Tiled Layer"];

//If I run this part alone, I'll get the satellite map.


AGSWebMap* webmap = [[AGSWebMap alloc] initWithItemId:@"bb9b8c172e8142f995526bf658078f54" credential:nil];
webmap.delegate = self;
[webmap openIntoMapView:self.mapView];

//When I add this webMap code and run the project, I get a blank white screen.


//.m cont.

- (void)mapViewDidLoad:(AGSMapView *) mapView {
NSLog(@"mapView didLoad");    
}

- (void) webMapDidLoad:(AGSWebMap*) webMap {
NSLog(@"webmap added successfully");
}

//Neither of these logs get called.
```

Questions.

1.) Is it right to use AGSTiledMapServiceLayer as my basemap? Also, is it right to use AGSWebMap for my ArcGIS Online map?

2.) My goal is to be able to add and remove multiple layers to and from a satellite basemap, one at a time. Am I on the right track?

I'm currently using MapBox to achieve this but I'm starting to experiment with ArcGIS SDK and it's features.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See answer for ObjC code.  I think you are the right track by updating a Web Map on top of a base map.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.  Make sure all 3 of these items are in the proper pace.

From the discussion from https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/objective-c/guide/viewing-web-map.htm.

Make these calls where you made them before (presumably `viewDidLoad`)

- instantiate an AGSWebMap object  // 1
- An instance of your class must then be set as the web map's delegate  // 2

  ```
  // 1
  AGSWebMap* webmap = [[AGSWebMap alloc] initWithItemId:@"bb9b8c172e8142f995526bf658078f54" credential:nil];
  // 2
  webmap.delegate = self;
  ```

---

Then update the handler `webMapDidLoad()`  // 3

```
  // open the web map into a map view in the delegate handler
- (void) webMapDidLoad:(AGSWebMap*) webMap {
    // 3
    [webmap openIntoMapView:self.mapView];  
    NSLog(@"webmap added successfully");
}
```